# Second tier sidebar navigation

Tags: menus, navigation, wp-list-pages

I'm trying to create a second level navigation in WordPress. I've found lots of examples, but none of them seem to do exactly what I want. This code below has me almost there, but I want an active class or better yet a way to only show the sub navigation if I'm on it. It would be great it WordPress had a depth_start option along with depth.

Example:

```
link1
link2 (active class)
  link2-1
  link2-2
  link2-3
link3
link4
```

Code so far:

```
<?php

$parent = array_reverse(get_post_ancestors($post->ID));
$first_parent = get_page($parent[0]);

$args = array(
    'depth'        => 0,
    'child_of'     => $first_parent->ID,
    'title_li'     => __($first_parent->post_title),
    'sort_column'  => 'menu_order',
); ?>

<nav class="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <?php wp_list_pages( $args ); ?> 
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have decided to use a CSS solution. I realized with the code above I do actually have classes I can work with. For example if you had this navigation in a  you could use something like this.

```
nav.sidebar li li li {
    display: none;
}
nav.sidebar li li.current_page_item > ul > li, nav.sidebar li li.current_page_ancestor > ul > li {
    display: block;
}
```

While not ideal, it gets the job done.